# IOS: custom UIAlertView don't work fine

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview

in this link

http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert

there is a sample of a custom alert view but it don't work fine because it have evere its classic rect of alertView.
In this link is written that:
To change the appearance from the default to our own background image drawRect: needs to be overridden. We do not call the super drawRect method to prevent UIAlertView from drawing the default appearance. All we do is draw our background image.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// do not call the super drawRect

CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
[self.backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
}
```

but it don't work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to do something like that using a UIAlertView.

I'd make a custom UIView and add that to your View when you want to display the message.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this custom class](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Setting-the-color-of-UIAlertView-in-iPhone-1585.php) to create a customized alert view without any issues.

Create a class with its header file, and paste the code from the URL above to each of `.m` and `.h` files. Import them into your project, and then import the header file into the class you the alert view for.

```
#import "ProAlertView.h"
```

and then call it where-ever you need. This is the method I've used to call the customized alert view:

```
- (void)processHasErrors
{
//Due to internet connection or server error.
ProAlertView *alert = [[ProAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NO_CONNECTION_ALERT_TITLE message: NO_CONNECTION_ALERT_MESSAGE delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NO_CONNECTION_ALERT_VIEW_DISMISS_BUTTON otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.07 green:0.19 blue:0.35 alpha:0.8] withStrokeColor: 
 [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1]];


[alert show];
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```